# How do i get to my Minecraft.jar? its not in my bin folder!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to open mc.jar, but everyone says its in bin, but for me bin only has backups in it! someone help please!
(P.S I am 1.8.7)

Answer (score 1):

**Since 1.6, Minecraft no longer uses the bin folder system.** Instead, there is a *versions* folder that holds Minecraft .jar files for each version you're using.

Since you're using 1.8.7, you'll have to assume the 1.8.7.jar file as being your minecraft.jar.